# Compression file doc pdf use 7zipsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, 7zip

//  This my code compress use 7 zip

```
  if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetfolder))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@Server.MapPath("~/bin/7z.Libs.16.2.1/bin/x64/7z.dll")); 
                        SevenZipCompressor sevenZipCompressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
                        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Ultra; // level compress
                        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma2; //method compress
                        sevenZipCompressor.CompressDirectory(sourceCodeFolder, Path.Combine(targetfolder, string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm") + fldr + ".zip")));
                    }

                    catch (Exception se)
                    {
                        SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(@Server.MapPath("~/bin/7z.Libs.16.2.1/bin/x86/7z.dll"));
                        SevenZipCompressor sevenZipCompressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
                        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Ultra; // level compress 
                        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma2; // method compress
```

//what is wrong my code?
                            sevenZipCompressor.CompressDirectory(sourceCodeFolder, Path.Combine(targetfolder, string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm")  + fldr + ".zip")));

```
                    }


                    Directory.Delete(@Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + fldr), true);
                    extractfrom = @Server.MapPath("~/Upload/ZIP/" + string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm")) + fldr + ".zip");

                    customSQL.ExecQueryString(" UPDATE TBL_PROGRESS_LEGAL_DOKUMEN set FileName = '" + string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm")  + namafile + ".zip"+ "'  , [FileSize] = '" + filesize + "'  where id_progress_legal_dokumen = '" + id_chekUpload.Text + "'"));
                    myfeedback._success("File Success Upload");
                }

                else
                {

                }
```

my question why 7zip make compress 7mb to be 6mb only?

Answer (score 1):

(Most) PDFs are already compressed and you cannot gain much by archiving them.

[Why don't some files compress very much?](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/104/)
[Which files does not reduce its size after compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136268/which-files-does-not-reduce-its-size-after-compression)

Comment: Ok thanks sir, how about the doc file i tried from 899 kb just be 715 kb, is it that way?

Comment: There is no general answer. If your DOC files contain a lot of (uncompressed) text, it's bad. If there a re a lot of (already compressed) JPGs - it's most likely fine.